# Converting List to Map

Tags: java, java-8

```
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*; 
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        newList.add(1);
        newList.add(2);
        newList.add(3);
        newList.add(4);
        int valueMap =1;
        Map<Integer,Integer> formMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>(); 
        Function<Integer,Map<Integer,Integer>> myFunc = i->{
          if(formMap.get(i)!=null)
          {
              formMap.replace(i,(formMap.get(i)+1));
          }
          else
          {
              formMap.put(i,valueMap);
          }
          return formMap;
        };

       Map<Integer,Integer> newMap =  newList.stream().map(i->myFunc.apply(i)).collect(Collectors.toMap(n->n, p->p,(a, b) -> a) );
        System.out.println(newMap);
    }
}
```

Im trying to convert my list to map by applying some operation on the object of the list but im getting the below error as follows:

```
error: incompatible types: inference variable K has incompatible bounds
       Map<Integer,Integer> newMap =  newList.stream().map(i->myFunc.apply(i)).collect(Collectors.toMap(n->n, p->p,(a, b) -> a) );
                                                                                      ^
    equality constraints: Integer
    lower bounds: Map<Integer,Integer>
  where K,T,U are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in method <T,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>,Function<? super T,? extends U>,BinaryOperator<U>)
    T extends Object declared in method <T,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>,Function<? super T,? extends U>,BinaryOperator<U>)
    U extends Object declared in method <T,K,U>toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>,Function<? super T,? extends U>,BinaryOperator<U>)
1 error
```

Comment: *"Im trying to convert my list to map by applying some operation on the object of the list"* - what operation? What should the keys/values in the resulting map be?

Comment: Try to debug, your Right hand does not match with left hand.

Answer (score 2):

Your `map` step transforms your `Stream<Integer>` to a `Stream<Map<Integer,Integer>>`.

Therefore, your `.collect(Collectors.toMap(...))` produces a

```
Map<Map<Integer,Integer>,Map<Integer,Integer>>
```

which can't be assigned to your

```
Map<Integer,Integer> newMap
```

variable.

Comment: Nicely pointed to mistake.

Comment: How to solve it?
Any other way around to make map from list?